# onBackPressed() и getView() в фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin

При нажатии кнопки "назад" onBackPressed() в MainActivity, вызывает в фрагменте itemClick(...), мне в этом методе нужно получить rootView из

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_file_list, container, false)

    return rootView
}
```

Я пытаюсь получить его с помощью getView() (view в Котлин), но он возвращает NULL, как от этого избавится?

```
    fun itemClick(selectedItem: String?) {
            if (view == null) {
                Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "View is NULL")
                return
            }
            val list = view!!.findViewById(R.id.list) as RecyclerView
            ...
```